# Custom field metabox not showing in back-end

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I recently updated my website after a while, and the custom fields meta box is not showing in the editor anymore. It isn't showing under "Screen Options" either. Any ideas why this could be, and how to get it back?

[image]

Comment: Is that screenshot coming from the edit page for a CPT? Maybe the CPT doesn't have custom fields enabled, or you need to re-enable it back after the update. There might also be a plugin which hides/disables the meta box on that page.

Comment: It is from a CPT, but it's just the same on regular posts.

Comment: Try to disable all plugins? And sorry, I meant "custom fields" when I said "meta box".

Comment: So, have you figured out the problem?

Comment: It's the ACF plugin that removes default custom fields display, but I haven't found a way around it. I need both ACF and default custom fields metaboxes.

Comment: @SallyCJ Found the solution! Posted an answer.

Comment: +1 for both the helpful answer and question. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the latest Advanced Custom Fields update (from version 5.6.0 on) removes the core custom fields metaboxes by default.

The way to restore it was to add a filter in `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

When registering a custom post type you have to declare that it supports the custom fields meta box to get it, e.g.:

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )
```

But most people don't do this, and build real metaboxes instead. This way instead they can put in radio buttons and drop downs etc

Comment: It's actually registered with custom fields support.