# Where can I enable custom fields in WP 4.9.?

Tags: custom-field

I used to enable custom fields on a Page edit Admin screen, just clicking on "Screen Options" in the top right.

However on a recent 4.9.8 installation, in the screen options I see only "layout" and "enable full-height editor".

Am I missing something or has this functionality been removed from the default install?

Comment: Is the a fresh install, any plugins running? Check out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317185/custom-field-metabox-not-showing-in-back-end/317230#317230

Comment: @pim exactly what I was looking for. can't mark as duplicate though